# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in np.exp(x**2)

Tags: python, numpy, exp

I need to calculate `exp(x**2)` where `x = numpy.arange(30,90)`. This raises the warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
inf
```

I cannot safely ignore this warning, but neither SymPy nor mpmath is a solution and I need to perform array operations so a Numpy solution would be my dream.

Does anyone know how to handle this problem?

Comment: For this *particular* case, using `numpy.longfloat` as a NumPy dtype might just work.  This depends on your platform, though: if you're lucky, `numpy.longfloat` is the 80-bit IEEE 754 extended precision type, usually padded with zero bytes so that it ends up being reported as `float128` or `float96`.  If you're unlucky, it'll just be the same as `numpy.float64`.  [If you're *very* lucky indeed, it'll be a genuine 128-bit type.]  But what's the use-case?  Why do you need to handle such enormous values?

Comment: `numpy.exp(numpy.longfloat(89**2))` -> `1.1132460315637997504e+3440`

Comment: It works perfectly fine, thank you! As input it takes the membrane potential that has characteristic values in that regime. It is just part of a calculation and is multiplied with another term.

Comment: Hmm.  You're dangerously close to the overflow limits, though, so I'd expect that there would still be problems with different input data.  (The 80-bit `longfloat` type overflows at around `1.19e+4932`.)  I'd definitely be looking for ways to keep track of the logs instead, as @GarethRees suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a data type that has the necessary range, for example [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> x = np.arange(Decimal(30), Decimal(90))
>>> y = np.exp(x ** 2)
>>> y[-1]
Decimal('1.113246031563799750400684712E+3440')
```

But what are you using these numbers for? Could you avoid the exponentiation and work with logarithms? More detail about your problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use this method to solve this problem:

> Normalized

I overcome the problem in this method. Before using this method, my classify accuracy is :86%. After using this method, my classify accuracy is :96%!!!
It's great!
first:
[Min-Max scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VmJo.gif)
second:
[Z-score standardization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYs0q.png)

These are common methods to implement `normalization`.
I use the first method. And I alter it. The maximum number is divided by 10. 
So the maximum number of the result is 10. Then exp(-10) will be not `overflow`!
I hope my answer will help you !(^_^)